# want to teach but not do research

Tags: research-process, teaching, mathematics

In Mathematics, where every university teacher is expected to do research I find it very difficult to do research without any motive. I keep thinking "this is a useless thing" If there are like minded people around to discuss problems which interests me, I do enjoy it, but alone I find no motive to do research The kind of mathematics I do do not have any practical applications, and those branches of mathematics which have applications do not interest me much.
Why are math faculty made to do research as mostly they are useless work? I like university level teaching and am good at it But a worse teacher who publishes papers have a greater chance of getting teaching jobs than a good teacher who does not do research

Comment: what country are you in?

Comment: Maybe I as a non-mathematitian don't understand this, but *why* are you interested in teaching something to your students that you either find boring (applied math) or useless (pure math)? Why do you want to work in math at all, research or teaching oriented?

Comment: So...not really sure what's "answerable" here.  Think we could all offer opinions but that's pretty much it, which makes this maybe not a good question for this forum.

Comment: In the US, there are opportunities to teach mathematics at community colleges; as far as I know, these positions have no research expectations. Most/all of these jobs require at least a Masters degree in math, though.

Comment: As to "why are faculty made to do research", see http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/51234/what-is-the-role-of-research-in-liberal-arts-college-faculty-evaluation

Comment: I like mathematics and and also teaching good students who enjoy learning it. Teaching gives a kind of satisfaction that you have done something useful, making some one understand some concept. But when one is not interested in doing research what is the point of making research compulsory specially because it is mostly no use to the society?

Comment: Essentially as long as I like what I am doing, I do not ask the question why am I doing it. Doing research is supposed to improve your teaching. But I dont think so

Comment: Try recasting your question to make it more answerable, and posting it on Math Educators SE.  For example, How does one find a pure teaching job that pays reasonably?  OR: How can I remain motivated to do required research when what I really enjoy is teaching?  Etc.

Answer (score 3):

`Why are math faculty made to do research as mostly they are useless work?`
You never know what is "useless" or not!

There are plenty of *teaching* universities where the faculty have a higher teaching load with little to no research expectations. Also, large research universities often have *teaching* faculty who primarily teach.